# SVG Repeating twice in IE 11,Works Fine in Chrome

Tags: svg, internet-explorer-11

This seems to be browser compatibility issue.I am using SVG in my component.Works Fine in Chrome.

```
<svg 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 15 15">
    <path d="M10 8.6l7.8-7.8 1.4 1.4L11.4 10l7.8 7.8 -1.4 1.4L10 11.4l-7.8 7.8 -1.4-1.4 7.8-7.8L0.8 2.2l1.4-1.4L10 8.6z"/>
</svg>
```

But in Internet Explorer 11 , It is coming twice(2 times).
What could be issue ?
Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: I am giving the width and height of SVG while using it !

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve].